# Pysftp open command with port number fails with "invalid port"

Tags: port, sftp, putty, psftp

I'm trying to use psftp (for the first time -- latest and greatest PuTTY installed), to connect to one of my servers. I'll call it `example.com`. On said server, I have sshd listening on a non-standard port (say, 1234). This works fine, since I can connect via SSH (using PuTTY, or anything else):

```
 ssh -p 1234 <user name>@example.com
```

No problem.

But, when I try psftp (using what I think should be equivalent syntax

```
 open example.com -P 1234 -l <user name>
```

I get the following error message:

> open: invalid port number

The psftp docs suggest I can use any port between 1 -> 65K or so, and I know port 1234 is valid (despite what psftp is telling me, since I can connect to said port using every other SFTP or SCP client I've tried), but just not psftp.

I must be missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of the [psftp `open` command](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp-cmd-open) is:

```
open [username@]hostname [port]
```

So in your case:

```
open username@example.com 1234
```

---

The syntax you have tried to use is [psftp command-line syntax](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp-starting).

So alternatively, instead of the `open`, you can "open" the session right on the commandline using:

```
psftp example.com -P 1234 -l <user name>
```

*It's similar as with OpenSSH `ssh` (there you also use commandline syntax).*

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. For ssh I use ssh -p 1234 username@host.com, which works fine. Apparently, psftp doesn't like the '-p' in front of the port, whereas ssh requires it. Doesn't much matter -- be nice if everything used similar syntax.